# Hyper-V R2 can't add a teamed NIC as External Network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, failover, failovercluster, broadcom

I have a Dell PowerEdge R710 running `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter` and which was part of a `Hyper-V Failover Cluster`. It has 8x `Broadcom BCM5709C NICs` and three are teamed together to be my "Virtual Machines Team". The team works fine, but I'm having an issue with Hyper-V. It refuses to create a virtual network out of the teamed adapter and errors out with a message that I don't have permissions to do so. When I check the teamed adapter's properties it is bound to the `Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol`, Hyper-V just never went the extra step of making it into a virtual network.

As I said above, this server was part of a `Hyper-V Failover Cluster` with another identical machine. The other machine has the exact same settings and it's teamed adapter is working fine as a virtual network in Hyper-V.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can try to get this working? My other option is to reload the OS again and see if that helps. Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Short of doing the OS reload (again) how about renaming the server. Since you are receving permission errors this <b><u>might</u></b> resolve your error (?)... if it does and you get everything connected the way you want then try renaming your server back.

Comment: Well, a little late for that, I already started the OS reloading. Actually it's already done, I'm now re-configuring it.

Comment: Are you running the latest Firmware, Drivers, and Management Software? If not, go update and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @ChrisS, yes, I have the latest firmware and drivers from Dell installed on the machine for everything, not just the NICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days of researching I think I've found the answer, and it was actually an issue with Hyper-V. Just to preset what was happening before I answer, I was attempting to optimize the host's network for Hyper-V. More on that can be [found here](https://serverfault.com/questions/460172/what-is-the-proper-hyper-v-r2-with-teamed-broadcom-bcm5709c-nics-configuration/461054).

Well, as part of the optimizations one of them was to add two registry entries. They are `BelowTenGigVmqEnabled` (also `TenGigVmqEnabled`) and `BelowTenGigVmChimneyEnabled` (also `TenGigVmChimneyEnabled`) to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters`. If those settings exist *before* you try to create a Hyper-V virtual network with a *teamed* adapter, you will get the permissions error. From what I saw, *physical* adapters don't have an issue if the settings exist or not when you create a virtual network out of them.

The proper way of using these settings is to configure the virtual network with Hyper-V then add the settings in and it all works fine. Also, I'm not sure if it was one or the other, but to be on the safe side I removed both, configured the virtual network, then added them back. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't mean to slam someone before I've read their whole post, but that Accepted Answer starts with incorrect information right off the bat (TOE = TCP Offload Engine; iSOE is the iSCSI Offload Engine; VERY different things). We run BCM5709 chips in our Hyper-V R2 cluster and mucking around with registry settings has never come up (seems like an awful idea).

Comment: Looks like I linked to the answer on the other post. Are you referring to my question or to the answer on it?

Comment: The answer, you're question seems reasonable.